# Differentiate Oracle SQL resultset by which WHERE clause item was matched?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am researching 11,500 health care claims, and I have the following query:

```
select distinct b.claim_nbr, b.SERV_NBR, a.Member_Nbr, b.AFF_NBR, b.YMDEFF, b.ymdend, b.Location
From (select distinct member_nbr, aff_nbr, ymdeff, ymdend
From service_x
Where claim_nbr in (######)) a
join service_x   b
on substr(a.aff_nbr,1,6) =  substr(b.aff_nbr,1,6)
and a.member_nbr = b.member_nbr and (b.ymdeff between a.ymdeff and a.ymdend)
order by 2;
```

The resultset will contain the field information for both the claims in my list as well as related claims (ones that match on member number, affiliation number, and date of service). I am trying to avoid inserting claims from my list one at a time into the query, but I also need some way to differentiate the resultset by which WHERE claim was matched.

I would love to do this using temp tables, but my permissions are read-only, my list of claims to research is not SELECT-able in this program, and my request for CREATE privileges is currently denied.

The program I am using (Benthic's Golden) is able to export to Excel on the client-side, so if I can get a client-side loop going (if this is even possible), I could put each resultset on a separate Excel sheet and do 40-50 at a time that way. Otherwise, I suppose the resultset would have to be one compilation. If possible, please teach me a way to differentiate different records in the resultset by which where clause item they matched, either through using a successful loop that allows me to export each individual claim's resultset to Excel or by an indicator within the resultset for many of the claims at once that would indicate which claim was matched in the where clause.

Thank you very much for considering my question.

EDIT: My final code after Politank-Z's help:

`select distinct b.claim_nbr, b.SERV_NBR, a.Member_Nbr, b.AFF_NBR, b.YMDEFF, b.ymdend, b.Location, a.origclm
    From (select distinct claim_nbr as origclm, member_nbr, aff_nbr, ymdeff, ymdend
    From service_x
    Where claim_nbr in (######)) a
    join service_x   b
    on substr(a.aff_nbr,1,6) =  substr(b.aff_nbr,1,6)
    and a.member_nbr = b.member_nbr and (b.ymdeff between a.ymdeff and a.ymdend)
    order by 8;
    Export excel`

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you would like to know what row match either on member number, affiliation number or date of service. Is that right?

Comment: You could use a macro enabled excel using either ODBC or ADODB connection to the SQL Server to pull the data. Apply logic as required and you could actually achieve what you wanted

Comment: Why not just add `claim_nbr` to the `SELECT` clause of your inner query and include it under an alias in the `SELECT` clause of your outer query?

Comment: @Rookie13, in plain English, the query shows all claims related to the claim in my WHERE clause, where related means they have the same member number, a similar afficiliation number, and a starting date of service between the start and end dates of the original claim.

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito I would love to do that and still might file another request, this time asking for the ODBC driver. This question is pretty much my last resort before that. I am decent with VBA so I would love to have that option available as well, but for now am assuming that there might be a way to do this with SQL where I don't have to petition the dbas.

Comment: @Politank-Z trying that now, will let you know if that works and then you can post as an answer and I can accept

Comment: @Politank-Z Yes, that worked! Thank you so much! To answer your question, I'm a noob at SQL, your answer made good sense. If you post that I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you wanted just needed to bubble up. Adding `claim_nbr` to the `SELECT` clause of your inner query and including it under an alias in the `SELECT` clause of your outer query wins the day.

```
select distinct a.claim_nbr ref_claim, b.claim_nbr, b.SERV_NBR, a.Member_Nbr, b.AFF_NBR,
b.YMDEFF, b.ymdend, b.Location
From (select distinct member_nbr, aff_nbr, ymdeff, ymdend, claim_nbr
From service_x
Where claim_nbr in (######)) a
join service_x   b
on substr(a.aff_nbr,1,6) =  substr(b.aff_nbr,1,6)
and a.member_nbr = b.member_nbr and (b.ymdeff between a.ymdeff and a.ymdend)
order by 2;
```